# How can i get a popup from the visual tree if the popup is at the RootVisual level in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, popup, windows-phone, visual-tree

I need to get a popup in the VisualTree which is a sibling of Application.Current.RootVisual. Is there a way to do this?

I couldn't find a way for this at the moment.

I have tried to get the parent of the RootVisual but it don't have such.

```
            var frame = Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame;
            FrameworkElement fi = (FrameworkElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(frame);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was wrong approach.

Here is the correct one and it works like a champ:

```
            System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Popup> popups = VisualTreeHelper.GetOpenPopups();
            Popup popup = popups.ElementAt(0);
```